# Postgresql extract last row for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data

| app | people | login |
| --- | --- | --- |
| slack | Jenny | 2019-01-01 |
| slack | Jenny | 2020-01-01 |
| slack | Jenny | 2021-01-01 |
| slack | Yang | 2020-06-01 |
| slack | Yang | 2021-06-01 |

For each group app and user, I need to get the latest login date. I tried to use a window function, but could not get the result of what I am expecting:

```
SELECT app, people, LAST_VALUE(login) OVER (PARTITION BY app, people ORDER BY login)
FROM xxxxx
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MAX` window function in place of the `LAST_VALUE` window function:

```
SELECT app, 
       people, 
       MAX(login) OVER (PARTITION BY app, people ORDER BY login DESC)
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nr3nHVatcVc1HRULydnTTr/2).

---

Instead, if you want to aggregate your "*app*" and "*people*" values on the last login value, you can also use the `MAX` aggregation function:

```
SELECT app, 
       people, 
       MAX(login)
FROM tab
GROUP BY app, 
         people
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nr3nHVatcVc1HRULydnTTr/1).

Comment: `ORDER` in `OVER` is important to return proper `LAST_VALUE` from a group. Without order it's quite random

Comment: You're right. Anyways `LAST_VALUE` really isn't the proper window function to use.

Answer (score 1):

To get first, last value from group there is no need for window function, just distinct select. I've assumed that each {appp, people} pair must be presented only once in results.

```
select distinct on (app,people)
app, people, login from tab
order by app, people, login desc
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=391236da9e56cf01a44ef8cd5b2c9159)

And example with `LAST_VALUE`

```
SELECT 
  app, 
  people, 
  LAST_VALUE(login) OVER (
         PARTITION BY app, people 
         ORDER BY login ASC 
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
                UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM tab
```

When `ORDER BY` is used inside window function then window function run in "running sum" mode, knowing only about rows already processed inside partition. If we want to get information from whole partition then we must explicitly point that.

In this case, using `MAX` looks like better choice (as @lemon pointed)

```
SELECT 
   app, 
   people, 
   login,  
   MAX(login) OVER (PARTITION BY app, people)
FROM tab
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I know your query will work, but why the window function do not do the job? any idea?

Comment: It really depends on whether you want to keep the same amount of rows or want to "*aggregate*" the rows. In the former case you need a window function, in the latter one you want an aggregation function. @yyiws

Comment: @yyiws window function also works, but you need to explicitly show that all rows in partition should be scanned

Comment: At that point use `MAX`, as long as it automatically implies your `RANGE` clause.